# How to disable green indicator on top for camera, mic and location?

Tags: android, shell

I tried

```
adb shell cmd device_config put privacy camera_mic_icons_enabled false default
```

but it keeps coming back and now even this is not working ? Is there are any way to disable it permanently ? My device is non rooted , please help me disable this annoying green notification/indicator . Is there any official way to disable it ?

Comment: This is a security feature which can not be disabled permanently for a good reason.

Comment: but i dont want this , please help me et rid of this feature

Comment: Sorry, but this is now standard on Android and iOS for detecting malware and stalking ware access to camera and mic in background.

Answer (score 0):

No, Above android 12 it indicates that your app is currently using camera, mic, or location whatever your currently accessing